# TableViewStyle doesn't change with Core Data (sometimes)

Tags: xcode, core-data, uitableview

I am developing an app with core data.
An user can add category's and than the user can add cells into the the category.
If the cell is `done`, the user set the cell to done.
If the category is called the view checks if all cells are `done`.
If all cells are done in Core Data it sets the category to `done` (with a `NSString:@"catisdone"`).
This works all fine.
I change the CellStyle with this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath called");

static NSString *notDoneCellIdentifier = @"NotDoneCatCell";
static NSString *doneCellIdentifier = @"DoneCatCell";

LWCats *currentCat = [self.cat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *cellIdentifier;
if ([currentCat.donecat isEqualToString:@"catisdone"]) {
    cellIdentifier = doneCellIdentifier;
} else {
    cellIdentifier = notDoneCellIdentifier;
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = currentCat.namecat;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentCat.rewardcat;

return cell; }
```

This works most time fine.
If there is a category in the tableView it is called (of course).
It works **not** good if I add a category, than I go to the category and add a cell, set this cell to `done`, save it and close the app.
If I open the app again the category is **not** changed to `done`, when I go to the category and go back the category is set to `done`.
I have tried many things (include call viewWillAppear (checks if all cells are done and set `NSString` to `done` or to `not done`) in the AppDelegate (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`)).

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by checking the category by setting up the cells (with an if-statement).